# How to show current tags filter in Shopify only if the current tags are more than 1

Tags: filter, shopify, liquid

I need help please with showing the tags filter only if the current tags **are more than 1**,
Currently my filter shows even in the case on a single tag. I tried the following but couldn't find the exact liquid syntax:

```
                  <dd>
                <ol>
                  {% for t in tags %}
                    {% assign tag = t | strip %}
                    {% assign tag_value = tag | handleize %} 

                    {% if current_tags contains tag %}
                    {% if current_tags > 1 %}
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{ tag_value }}" checked/>
                        <label>{{ tag }}</label>
                      </li>
                    {% else %}
                      {% if collection.tags contains tag %} 
                        <li>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="{{ tag_value }}"/>
                          <label>{{ tag }}</label>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </ol>
              </dd>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if condition to check current tags are more than 1

```
{% if current_tags.size > 1 %}
{% endif %}
```